# Error de Inicio de Sesión con Facebook y flutter

Tags: flutter, facebook-api

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy implementado el inicio de sesión con facebook, cuando la descargo de la play store el login funciona bien con la web pero cuando la app de facebook esta instalada, no funciona, esto pasa solo cuando es descarga de la google play, en desarrollo funciona bastante bien

Comment: Agrega el código por favor,  en Google Play no funciona pero si cuando la subes a tu cel directamente?..

Answer (score 0):

Hey gente tuve el mismo problema y lo solucione en el siguiente hilo https://stackoverflow.com/a/58283922. ademas adiciono la imagen de donde deben sacar el sha1 en google console que se genera en una version a producción [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este sha debe convertirlo en su terminal con esta linea `echo SHA1_here | xxd -r -p | openssl base64`  y el resultado ponerlo en su facebook developer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]